# Как сделать анимированную кнопку на css

Tags: html, css

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста как сделана анимированная кнопка на этом сайте: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://diopter.kwst.net/site/onepage.html) (Самый первый слайд, кнопка называется Our Portfolio). Когда наводишь вылазит глаз

Интересует готовое решение на ксс. Кто может помочь?

Comment: F12 и смотри, как они это сделали...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так (менять `top`):

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 14px 22px 14px 22px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #292929;
    background: #292929;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn i {
    top: -100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.btn span {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.btn:hover i{
  top: 0px;
}

.btn:hover span{
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
  
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Portfolio</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость, но можете помочь еще в одной вещи. Все та же анимация. По вашему примеру я сделал анимацию для "линий" которые плавно выростают если навести мышью на фото в разделе портфолио. Прошу посмотрите: http://onedaytv.ru , Верхняя линия у меня вылазит как надо, а вот нижнюю я хотел бы что бы она выростала не сверху вниз как сейчас а наоборот, снизу вверх. Я пробовал уже переворачивать на 180 град, но не помогло. Можете помочь изменить мой ксс что бы получить то что надо. Скажите что можно поменять, пожалуйста:)

Comment: @iSeeDev, Вы об этом https://jsbin.com/pagedel/edit?html,css,output ?

Comment: нет, я вот о чем. Наведите мышкой на фото где парень с девушкой. У вас фото затемнится и под кнопкой "просмотреть" есть вертикальная линия. У нее анимация такая же как и у верхней линии, она появляется с верху вниз, а я бы хотел что бы она появлялась снизу вверх. Можете пересмотреть?)

Comment: @iSeeDev, https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/xdEGYv?editors=1100

Comment: чудесно! Я вам очень благодарен! Спасибо большое!